# What is the English expression for this facial expression?

Tags: expressions

Any expression for this?

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the meaning of this expression in cultural context? And in more words? Do you happen to know if there is a particular expression for this in another language (like say Farsi) that can at least be translated?

Comment: Without more context, you're likely to get a wide variety of answers, from positive to negative meanings. Can you tell us more that doesn't rely on interpreting just the image? Is the expression well-known in pictures online of a certain type, for example (like the meme one answerer has suggested) or does it occur in a particular situation?

Comment: E.g. Is he saying *Not bad*, or is he saying *Smells awful*?

Comment: It's difficult to give a definitive answer as gestures/expressions vary across cultural boundaries. Semi-jokingly - this expression could be  applied as, "Hey, I shagged your wife yesterday!" <EXPRESSION> "Really...Which one?" - Nonplussed, flummoxed, disinterested could cover it :)

Comment: As someone who has worked with both Quebecois and Parisians, I can say it's a typically Gallic facial expression...

Comment: This question needs more context. The photo may help *support* the expression you are looking for, but without a description, users are only guessing what expression will answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a Google image search on **moue**. I think it matches pretty well.

Comment: Yup, that's the word that came to mind as soon as I saw it.

Comment: I'm torn here.  This is a great word, and I'm all for giving it more exposure.  But most of those images look nothing like the picture in the question.  Images for *sturgeon face* (mentioned in the comments for sequoia's answer) seem to match better, in my opinion.  But back to the plus side, the intent behind *moue* and *sturgeon face* are similar (namely disdain or distaste).  (I'm not convinced the expression posted is meant to be disdainful though, due to the raised eyebrows.)

Comment: Oh, I should quickly add that I'm now noticing that some sources indicate *sturgeon face* is meant disdainfully, while others agree more with the "not bad" interpretation.  I do think it has a lot to do with the eyebrows.

Comment: @JohnY: I wish I could find an illustration rather than the images, which I agree are all over the place. ( Ahmedinejad's is a classic moue.) That being said, it's a difficult expression; I myself cannot pull it off well at all.

Answer (score 6):

"Not bad!" as in "That's pretty good!"  It's a look of approval, suggesting that one is impressed with what they see and that the presenter has earned their respect to some degree.

sources: [Know your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/obama-rage-face-not-bad?search=1&utm_campaign=site_search&utm_source=web&utm_medium=search_results#.ToTTEc2EppQ) | [Wiktionary](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/not_bad)

Comment: The context of the similar photo of Ahmadinejad on a [Newsweek cover](http://therewillbewar.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/newsweek_ahmadinejad_cover1.jpg) suggests the opposite of good, with headline (at first glance) reading "Everything about Iran is Wrong".  (The phrase "you think you know" after "Everything" is much less visible.)  Note, this [photo of Ahmadinejad](http://www.flickr.com/photos/11646741@N05/2126888881/) is perhaps the source of the image in the question.  Your meme reference uses title "[Sturgeon Face](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/sturgeon-face)".

Comment: well, given the amount of context provided with the question, trying to give a definitive answer is a fools errand; it's like trying to answer "what's 1 + x ?" without knowing x.  Given that fact, I stand firmly by my answer!  If that's not a "not bad" face, I'm the queen of England. :)

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell - Good day, Your Majesty... How's it hangin'?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward answer would be a *[frown](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frown)*, but like others have commented, facial expressions are subject to cultural interpretation. (In particular, the raised eyebrows are somewhat at odds with the extremely downward-turned mouth.)

Answer (score 2):

Another option: **Pretentious**. Like an "I'm better than you" face.

Answer (score 1):

In English as in French: 'Pffff'.

Answer (score 1):

Reserved expression of approval